# May a compiler remove a local variable in favor of multiple memory accesses?

Tags: c, embedded

We had a discussion on how to ensure that data in some shared (untrusted) memory region is only accessed once, copied to local memory, and then checked and processed from there. Environment is an embedded multicore µC with shared RAM for IPC, code is written in C99.
Currently, we basically do `Type local_copy = *(Type*)shared_memory_pointer;` and then only operate on `local_copy` afterwards.

Now a colleague brought up the question, whether the compiler was allowed to not perform the copy into local memory and instead access the data at `shared_memory_pointer` directly in the following, which (in theory) would allow for manipulation of the data while it is used.

Is it possible that a compiler does that? If so, how can we make sure that it does not happen? If not, please explain the details.

Thanks all!

Edit: there is no OS on the core in question, it is a bare-metal system.

Comment: `instead access the data at shared_memory_pointer directly in the following, which (in theory) would allow for manipulation` How can you manipulate the data using a copy? `then only operate on local_copy afterwards` whatever compiler does, can't change the maning of you code - if you operate on a copy and change a copy, it can't affect the original. The access to the shared pointer could be for _reading_, not writing.

Comment: @KamilCuk he asks if the compiler might optimize away the copy. I think, adding some `volatile` voodoo would prevent this.

Comment: @KamilCuk I think that the compiler is allowed to reload `shared_memory_pointer` as long it can prove that none of operations in between can affect value stored in `shared_memory_pointer`

Comment: I think that you must load the value using some atomic operation. Like `atomic_load`. This will prevent the compiler from reordering operations or splitting the load.

Comment: Code such as `Type local_copy = *(Type*)shared_memory_pointer;` is code smell and a strong indication that you have undefined behavior or other type-related bugs in your program.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks, but I'd argue the type punning is safe in that case, please correct me if I'm wrong: `shared_memory_pointer` is an aligned `void*` and `Type` is just providing some structure to the raw bytes in the shared memory. It is never accessed anywhere outside of this single line.

Answer (score 2):

> whether the compiler was allowed to not perform the copy into local memory and instead access the data at shared_memory_pointer directly

Yes the compiler is allowed to do that. The only scenario where you can enforce a read is by `volatile` qualified access. In your case both the local variable and the cast should be `volatile` qualified.

Note however...

- `volatile` doesn't solve re-entrancy issues. You need a mutex, critical section or similar means to block the code from race condition bugs. Use the means provided by your OS.
- `Type local_copy = *(Type*)shared_memory_pointer;` is very fishy code and suggests that you have undefined behavior or type-related bugs in your program. Wild type punning like this might cause misalignment, incorrect strict pointer aliasing optimizations, discarded qualifiers and so on - all of it undefined behavior. Besides, if you have picked proper types there is no need to cast in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! No question about volatile in cast, but why should the local variable be volatile qualified in your opinion? Doesn't this only enfore assuming external changes at any time, i.e., reloading from memory for every access? That is not needed for the local copy.

I'd argue the type punning is safe in that case, please correct me if I'm wrong: `shared_memory_pointer` is an aligned `void*` and `Type` is just providing some structure to the raw bytes in the shared memory. It is never accessed anywhere outside of this single line.

Comment: @Gileos You just need to ensure that the access happens at that it happens at the point when you want it to happen. The compiler isn't allowed to re-order `volatile` access. As for what happens in the underlying hardware, that's another story. You'll wish to ensure that the variable isn't cached in case your CPU(s) have data cache, for example.

Comment: As for the pointed-at data, `void*` isn't relevant, it's just a go-between. If the compiler is unaware of the type of the actual stored data, you can type pun it in case you always use that same type every time.  If it's accessed as a different type then UB.

Comment: Got it. Strict aliasing rule is not violated in our case, so the punning is safe here.

Comment: The gist of it is that the shared memory is used for one-way IPC. The other core uses the same struct `Type` and writes it to that memory, on our core we read that struct and verify that the fields make sense for the request. For other modes of operation the shared memory is used differently, so a direct interpretation the memory as `Type*` is not possible.

Comment: I guess the solution could also be reading the value via atomic variable. Alternatively, by a normal read within some critical section that ends with read-memory-barrier

Answer (score 0):

> We had a discussion on how to ensure that data in some shared
> (untrusted) memory region is **only accessed once**, copied to local
> memory, and then checked and processed from there.

Use `memcpy` with binary semaphore instead of pointer punning.

freeRTOS example:
It makes sure that the

```
if(xSemaphoreTake( xSemaphoreSharedVariable, (TickType_t) 10 ) == pdTRUE) 
{
    taskENTER_CRITICAL(); //make sure that the shared resource will not be changed during not atomic access
    memcpy(&local_copy, shared_memory_pointer, sizeof(local_copy);
    taskEXIT_CRITICAL();
}
else
{
    /* the shared resource was alredsy read */
    /* do something */
}
```

Comment: how `memcpy` is fundamentally different from type punning if the OP's compiler supports it?

Comment: the problem is not how to copy data but rather how to prevent the compiler form reordering loads after `taskEXIT_CRITICAL()` (whatever it is... )

Comment: I don't think it is relevant. If type punning solution worked that the alignment was correct

Comment: https://www.freertos.org/taskENTER_CRITICAL_taskEXIT_CRITICAL.html mentions only disabling/enabling interrupt. It says nothing about a memory barrier at "EXIT". I guess there must some implicit barrier there

Comment: the compiler may not use "strict aliasing rule". Therefore this load may be defined for this particular implementation. Preventing multiple reloads it the issue

Comment: have you heard about "-fno-strict-aliasing" ?